# SQL query returns too much identical column data using C#

Tags: c#, sql, select

Here's the section:

```
    string sql = "select col1, product_id, col3, col4, col[n], col100 from inventory where store_code = '" + sStore + "' order by product_id";

    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, conn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    string sColl = "";
    while (dr.Read()) {
       if (dr["product_id"].ToString() != sColl) {
          if (dr["product_id"].ToString() != " " && dr["product_id"].ToString() != "") {
              ...
              Console.WriteLine(dr["product_id"].ToString()) //checking 
              [operational code]
              ...
          }
       }
       sColl = dr["product_id"].ToString();
    }
```

It is my ham-fisted attempt to make the operational code (near the middle there) worked on *only once* for each distinct product_id in the cascade of repetitions of the same product_id before a subsequent different product_id is reached.  The problem is, of course, I have to wait a long time for the routine to finish.  The operational code is getting used only once for each unique product_id, thankfully, but I have to wait for the routine to wade through a million other of *the same* product_ids.

In other words, at present, visualized with output where the [operational code] is, half a vertical mile of repetitive, identical product id "0002000038" is currently getting dumped into a Console.WriteLine(dr["product_id"].ToString()) before it changes to another vert. half mile of "0066133890," and on and on for several more minutes until 10 or so product_ids are done with.

**What I really need instead:**
I'm hoping for a way to rewrite the above code so that instead of:

```
0002000038
0002000038
0002000038
0002000038
0002000038
0002000038
0002000038
...[half a mile more of this]
0002000038
0066133890
0066133890
0066133890
0066133890
0066133890
0066133890
0066133890
...[half a mile more of this]
0066133890
...
```

the output would just be:

```
0002000038
0066133890
...
```

Comment: Some unrelated tips: Store `dr["product_id"].ToString()` in a variable rather than repeating the index lookup via the column name and the conversion to string **five** times. Also `OracleCommand` and `OracleDataReader` are both `IDisposable` so should be in `using` blocks. The connection isn't shown in the snippet, but that is as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `product_id` is the only column you're using, you don't need to query the other fields. Once you've done this, the `distinct` keyword should do the trick:

```
SELECT   DISTINCT product_id
FROM     inventory
WHERE    store_code = /* something */
ORDER BY product_id
```